# ways to fix request entity too large error when importing a .csv file in php

Tags: php

I am trying to import some data from a .csv file to php and it keeps showing 413 request entity too large error. I searched online and did some modifications in IIS (uploadReadAheadSize & maxRequestEntityAllowed) but it didn't fix it. The file i am trying to upload is 24.8MB. Does anyone have some idea on what i can modify next for php to accept the file?

Comment: can you share the code you're using please?

Comment: update your `php.ini` settings too if not done already. `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` should be set accordingly.